# Incorrect string value: '\x99\xC1\xE8\x89u\

Tags: php, mysqli

Using a prepared statement in PHP...

```
$sql = "insert into `customers` (`name`, `email`) values (?, AES_ENCRYPT(?,?))";
$mysqli = $oDB->connect(); // see below for $oDB class and connect function
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $key);
$stmt->execute();
```

... I'm trying to encrypt the email so it's stored a little more securely (or at least so that dumping the contents of the `customers` table doesn't show the email in plain text)

(`$key` is a randomly generated string of 32 characters, if that's relevant)

The database and tables use `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` coding.
And I've tried setting the connection charset before executing the statement...

```
class oDB {
    public function connect() {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($this->db['host'], $this->db['user'], $this->db['pass'], $this->db['name']);
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");
        return $mysqli;
};
```

Upon executing the sql the program returns the error `Incorrect string value: '\x99\xC1\xE8\x89u\'`

Looking up this code I get solutions about setting the charset on the mysqli connection before sending the sql. But somehow that doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to resolve the `incorrect string value` error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: @Jens That wouldn't cause this error.

Comment: @Jens, corrected the query, I used single-quotes because markdown was messing up the query. It's correctly shown now.

Comment: Well, that string doesn't appear to be valid UTF-8…

Comment: @deceze, care to elaborate on how I can make it valid UTF-8?

Comment: Care to elaborate where that string comes from in the first place and why it's not UTF-8?

Comment: `$email` comes from a form and is sanitized as string. `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`
Or are you referring to another string?

Comment: After setting the collation for the field `email` to `latin1_general_ci` the encrypt works.